# Not able to load images using webapck, react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using webpack in react project, However images are not getting loaded
Error in console is image is not found
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/test.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
```

This is my webpack configuration

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const path = '/../../assets/images/test.jpg'

class DashboardContainer extends Component {
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const { history } = this.props
    console.log(history)
  }

  render() {
    console.log('here')
    return (
      <div>
           <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click me</button>
           <img src={path} width="400" height="400" alt="logo"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(DashboardContainer)
```

[My image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CzN9.png)

Comment: Might be the first slash in the path, try `const path = '../../assets/images/test.jpg'`. Also, you can add your assets in the `/public` folder.

Comment: Did not resolve even after removing first slash